# Wake Locking while running a service

Tags: android, service, android-wake-lock

I am wondering simply is this the correct way to implement a Wake Lock to make my device come back on after it has been in sleep mode. After the device is back on it will then launch an intent from that point. Really I just want to make the screen come on long enough for the intent to take place. Am I doing this correctly if not pointers would be great!

```
public class GMeter extends Service implements SensorEventListener {

private float mLastX, mLastY, mLastZ;
private boolean mInitialized;
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mAccelerometer;
private final float NOISE = (float) 2.0;
private PowerManager.WakeLock wl;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate() {
    mInitialized = false;
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mAccelerometer = mSensorManager
            .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Starting Service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    float x = event.values[0];
    float y = event.values[1];
    float z = event.values[2];
    double a = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2));
    double currentG = (a / SensorManager.STANDARD_GRAVITY);
    if (!mInitialized && currentG > 0.5) {
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(GMeter.this).create();
        alert.setTitle("-=Warning=-");
        alert.setMessage("Incoming Game!");
        alert.show();
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP + PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "myTag");
        wl.acquire();
        wl.release();
        mLastX = x;
        mLastY = y;
        mLastZ = z;
        mInitialized = true;
        // Start Second Activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(GMeter.this, nextClass.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        float deltaX = Math.abs(mLastX - x);
        float deltaY = Math.abs(mLastY - y);
        float deltaZ = Math.abs(mLastZ - z);
        if (deltaX < NOISE)
            deltaX = (float) 0.0;
        if (deltaY < NOISE)
            deltaY = (float) 0.0;
        if (deltaZ < NOISE)
            deltaZ = (float) 0.0;
        mLastX = x;
        mLastY = y;
        mLastZ = z;
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

No, wakelocks are used to prevent a device from sleeping. I guess you should use AlarmManager functionality to wake up your device and send an intent (with parameter `RTC_WAKEUP`).

Edit: If you want your functionality in `onCreate()` method of your service you should acquire PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK and you should release it in `onDestroy()`. Thus, you service will receive notifications. Or you can wake your device every n seconds and check your sensors.